# Изменение размера стандартной метки

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Есть маленький размера кластера, и большие метки.
Как можно уменьшить размер обычной метки?

```js
json = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": 1,
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          55.6297, 37.4589
        ]
      },
      "options": {
        "preset": "islands#blueCircleIcon",
        "iconColor": "rgba(0,200,0,0.8)",
        "iconOffset": [0, -25],
        "hasBalloon": false,
      }
    }, {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": 2,
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          55.6296, 37.4603
        ]
      },
      "options": {
        "preset": "islands#blueCircleIcon",
        "iconColor": "rgba(0,200,0,0.8)",
        "iconOffset": [0, -25],
        "hasBalloon": false,
      }
    }, {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": 1,
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          55.6290, 37.4601
        ]
      },
      "options": {
        "preset": "islands#blueCircleIcon",
        "iconColor": "rgba(0,200,0,0.8)",
        "iconOffset": [0, -25],
        "hasBalloon": false,
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": 1,
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          55.6299, 37.4594
        ]
      },
      "options": {
        "preset": "islands#blueCircleIcon",
        "iconColor": "rgba(200,0,0,0.8)",
        "iconOffset": [0, -25],
        "hasBalloon": false,
      }
    }
  ]
}

ymaps.ready(init);

function init(ym) {
  let map = new ym.Map('map', {
    center: [55.6296, 37.4594],
    zoom: 16,
    controls: [
      'zoomControl',
      'searchControl',
    ],
  }, {
    searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
  });

  map.controls.get('zoomControl').options.set('size', 'large');
  map.controls.get('searchControl').options.set('size', 'small');

  let objectManager = new ym.ObjectManager({
    clusterize: true,
    gridSize: 64,
    clusterIconLayout: "default#pieChart",
    "clusterIconOffset": [0, -25],
    clusterIconPieChartRadius: 8,
    clusterIconPieChartCoreRadius: 0,
    clusterIconPieChartStrokeWidth: 0,
    hasBalloon: false,
  });

  map.geoObjects.add(objectManager);

  objectManager.add(json);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="ru" lang="ru">

<head>
  <title>Map</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&coordorder=latlong"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    html,
    body,
    #map {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задайте цвет метки, какой вы её хотите видеть в кластере-диаграмме и собственное изображение нужного размера для метки:

```
iconColor: '#4C4DA2',
iconLayout: 'default#image',
iconImageHref: 'https://sandbox.api.maps.yandex.net/examples/ru/2.1/icon_customImage/images/ball.png',
iconImageSize: [10, 12]
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g94m38qn/